# Event Not getting fired using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing screen scraping of one of the HTML web page. I am facing one issue while updating value of one of the TextBox using javascript.

Working Scenario:
There is one checkbox, Text Box control and update button on the webpage. If I update the date in that textbox using keyboard and check the checkbox, then on click of update button, date is updated of the selected HTMLTable row above and all the subsequent rows below.

Problem Statement: 
when I check the checkbox, set value in the text box and click on update button using Javascript, date is updated of the selected HTMLTable row but subsequent rows are not getting updated. I have tried many things but it's not working.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Below is the code I have tried

```
document.getElementById('WIN_0_rc0id536871178').checked = true;
document.getElementById('arid_WIN_0_536871020').value = "29/03/2017 00:00:00";

event = new Event('change');
document.getElementById('arid_WIN_0_536871020').dispatchEvent(event);
document.getElementById('WIN_0_536870298').click();
```

Comment: And how exactly are you updating the 'subsequent rows'?
Cause I only see you updating one checkbox and one row. (An ID can only be used on one HTML Element)

Comment: Yes, @RefugnicEternium is right. Can you also include the HTML part of your code please? Without it we won't be able to help. A code snippet would be great.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Subsequent rows are getting updated automatically when we check that checkbox and update date of one HTMLRow. That is application behavior. When we do it manually through webpage using mouse, if we check the check box, select the date and update for one htmlrow , it get revised for all the subsequent row.  I doubt that when i am doing programmatically, some event is not getting fired.